# building avahi: missing QtCore

Tags: linux, avahi

I am trying to build Avahi from source. ./configure tells me I am missing package "QtCore" but for the life of me I can't find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please state your distribution. On debian, installing "libqt4-dev" should suffice.